# Adding notebook tabs in tkinter - how do I do it with a class-based structure? (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I wrote a tkinter application that had widgets displayed on two frames, similar to this example, which successfully runs.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.title("Example")

notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
frame1 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
frame2 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
notebook.add(frame1, text="Frame One")
notebook.add(frame2, text="Frame Two")
notebook.pack()

#(The labels are examples, but the rest of the code is identical in structure). 

labelA = ttk.Label(frame1, text = "This is on Frame One")
labelA.grid(column=1, row=1)

labelB = ttk.Label(frame2, text = "This is on Frame Two")
labelB.grid(column=1, row=1)

root.mainloop()
```

I decided that I should try to restructure the program to use a class (which I'm admittedly not very familiar with). However, I'm unsure what I should do to allow the widgets to appear on different frames (everything else works okay). For instance, the following produces a "TypeError: **init**() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given." So presumably I'd need to initialise with an extra argument, but I'm not sure how the notebook would be worked into that, or if that's even the approach I should be taking. (The program will run if the "frame1" and "frame2" arguments are removed from the labels, it will, however, display the same thing on both frames).

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class MainApplication(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.labelA = ttk.Label(self, frame1, text = "This is on Frame One")
        self.labelA.grid(column=1, row=1)

        self.labelB = ttk.Label(self, frame2, text = "This is on Frame Two")
        self.labelB.grid(column=1, row=1)

root = Tk()
root.title("Example")
notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
frame1 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
frame2 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
notebook.add(frame1, text="Frame One")
notebook.add(frame2, text="Frame Two")
notebook.pack()
MainApplication(root).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I'm interested in a solution, but I'm also interested in learning what the class is doing differently compared to the standalone widgets.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Showing blocks of code out of context isn't very useful.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley  modified

Comment: I just watched a youtube video which I think describes exactly what your looking for. Here is a link to the series [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HjNHATw6XgY&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDclKx-QpC9wntnURXVJqLyk)  I think it is covered in the first couple videos. this guy creates a class which will essentially create multiple tabs for your multiple windows.

Comment: @Joe That seems like it'd work, although it's relatively convoluted and doesn't use a notebook. Surely there should be a simple way to convert my first example into a class.

Answer (score 7):

This would be one way to generalize the application as a class.  You want to eliminate the repeated code.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Notebook:

    def __init__(self,title):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title(title)
        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self.root)

    def add_tab(self,title,text):
        frame = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)
        self.notebook.add(frame,text=title)
        label = ttk.Label(frame,text=text)
        label.grid(column=1,row=1)
        self.notebook.pack()

    def run(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

nb = Notebook('Example')
nb.add_tab('Frame One','This is on Frame One')
nb.add_tab('Frame Two','This is on Frame Two')
nb.run()
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you split the different Frames within notebook into separate files.
I used from tab2 import * because I wanted this to remain in the namespace without adding the file/class prefix ie. I didn't want to write: tab1.Tab1(notebook)

main.py

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

from tab1 import *
from tab2 import *    

class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

    notebook = ttk.Notebook(parent)

    Tab1frame = Tab1(notebook)
    Tab2frame = Tab2(notebook)

    notebook.add(Typ1frame, text='TAB1')
    notebook.add(Typ2frame, text='TAB2')
    notebook.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    MainApplication(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

tab1.py

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Typ14(tk.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
    shell_frame=tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Sample Label Frame", padx=5,pady=5)
    shell_frame.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)
```

Answer (score 2):

To ensure that your code is clear and purposeful, you should create a class for your main application, and a class for each tab. You don't *need* to separate tab classes into separate files, but if you're working with other developers it would be in your best interest.

The code below shows your code reformatted to have 3 classes: 1 for the main app (MainApplication), and 2 for each tab (Frame1 and Frame2). In addition, I've `import`ed `tkinter as tk` for referential clarity.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class MainApplication(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title("Example")
        self.geometry('300x300')

        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self)

        self.Frame1 = Frame1(self.notebook)
        self.Frame2 = Frame2(self.notebook)

        self.notebook.add(self.Frame1, text='Frame1')
        self.notebook.add(self.Frame2, text='Frame2')

        self.notebook.pack()

class Frame1(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__()

        self.labelA = ttk.Label(self, text = "This is on Frame One")
        self.labelA.grid(column=1, row=1)

class Frame2(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__()

        self.labelB = ttk.Label(self, text = "This is on Frame Two")
        self.labelB.grid(column=1, row=1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MainApplication()
    app.mainloop()
```

As you can imagine, this will allow you to create additional classes to add frames to your tab classes. The code below shows an alteration to `class Frame1` above, and the addition of `class Frame1FrameA` which does just this.

```
class Frame1(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)

        self.labelA = ttk.Label(self, text = "This is on Frame One")
        self.labelA.grid(column=1, row=1)

        self.frame = Frame1FrameA(self)
        self.frame.grid(row=1, columnspan=2)

class Frame1FrameA(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)

        self.LabelA = ttk.Label(self, text="LabelA in FrameA in tab Frame1")
        self.LabelA.grid(column=0, row=0)

        self.LabelB = ttk.Label(self, text="LabelB in FrameA in tab Frame1")
        self.LabelB.grid(column=1, row=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

> The program will run if the "frame1" and "frame2" arguments are
> removed from the labels, it will, however, display the same thing on
> both frames

Error:

```
line 8, in __init__
    self.labelA = ttk.Label(self, frame1, text = "This is on Frame One")
TypeError: Label.__init__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

The problem can be fix.

- In line 8 and 11, change this `ttk.Label(self,..` to
  `ttk.Label(frame1,..`

Code:

```
self.labelA = ttk.Label(frame1, text = "This is on Frame One")
self.labelA.grid(column=1, row=1)

self.labelB = ttk.Label(frame2, text = "This is on Frame Two")
self.labelB.grid(column=1, row=1)
```

Screenshot:

[image]